# MVC Web App - Azure AD and External Account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure and hence need someone to guide me. I am trying to build a web app where internal users can be authenticated via Azure AD and external users via their external/social account. I understand Azure B2C allows for that approach. Below is what I have found:

Internal users on Azure AD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant

External users - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/gigya-tutorial

Sample MVC Code - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C

Can someone please help me with the following:

Am I correct in my approach and the sample MVC code?
Theoretically, how will the MVC web app know when to redirect to internal and when to external provider on B2C tenant?
Will all internal users be available in my B2C tenant?

Answer (score 0):

here is some documentation on how to do this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga

you need to create a policy that allows for multiple tenants in b2c. then add the claims provider for your allowed "azure ad tenants"